# Register multiple keyed or named services

Tags: c#, autofac

I need to register multiple services which are of the same interface but differs by any string constraint. To be more concrete:

```
[EventName("Domain/Task/Actions/Save")]
public class EntitySavedEventReceiver1 : IEventReceiver
{
    public void Receive(RemoteEvent evnt)
    {
    }
}

[EventName("Domain/Task/Actions/Save")]
public class EntitySavedEventReceiver2 : IEventReceiver
{
    public void Receive(RemoteEvent evnt)
    {
    }
}
```

The registration I tried:

```
foreach (Type eventReceiverType in mainAssembly.GetTypes().Where(x => typeof (IEventReceiver).IsAssignableFrom(x)))
{
    var attributes = eventReceiverType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (EventNameAttribute), false);

    foreach (var attribute in attributes.Cast<EventNameAttribute>())
    {
        builder.RegisterType(eventReceiverType)
            .Keyed<IEventReceiver>(attribute.EventName)
            // tried also named
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
    }
}
```

and resolving func:

```
builder.Register<Func<string, IEnumerable<IEventReceiver>>>(c =>
    {
        var ctx = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
        return eventName =>
            {
                var eventReceiver = ctx.ResolveKeyed<IEventReceiver>(eventName);
                return new [] { eventReceiver };
            };
    });
```

This works perfect but I need to register multiple services on the same name or key and have an ability to resolve them all.

Comment: I'm' pretty sure `ResolveKeyed<IEnumerable<IEventReceiver>>(name)` will work.

Comment: Damn.. so easy. Thank you!

Comment: @default.kramer yours should be an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ctx.ResolveKeyed<IEnumerable<IEventReceiver>>(eventName)
```

See [Relationship Types](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RelationshipTypes) for reference.